# url of webapi, how to configure in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, routes, global-asax

I Have a url to a webapi, like this:

```
http://Dynamicweb8724.nl/webapi/NavToDW/?process="
```

and in the mvc project I have this files:

```
public class RouteConfig
{

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            url: "DefaultApi/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Guestbook", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, PageID = 1067 }
        );

    }
}

public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "webapi/NavToDW",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }    
}
```

and the Global.asax file:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new Dynamicweb.AspNet.Views.RazorViewEngine());
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new Dynamicweb.AspNet.Views.WebFormViewEngine());
        // Fires when the application is started
        Dynamicweb.Frontend.GlobalAsaxHandler.Application_Start(sender, e);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
    }

    public void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fires when the session is started
        Dynamicweb.Frontend.GlobalAsaxHandler.Session_Start(sender, e);
    }

    public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fires at the beginning of each request
        //GlobalAsax.Application_BeginRequest(sender, e);
    }

    public void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fires upon attempting to authenticate the use
        Dynamicweb.Frontend.GlobalAsaxHandler.Application_AuthenticateRequest(sender, e);
    }

    public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fires when an error occurs
        Dynamicweb.Frontend.GlobalAsaxHandler.Application_Error(sender, e);
    }

    public void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fires when the session ends
        Dynamicweb.Frontend.GlobalAsaxHandler.Session_End(sender, e);
    }

    public void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fires when the application ends
        Dynamicweb.Frontend.GlobalAsaxHandler.Application_End(sender, e);
    }

    public void Application_OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dynamicweb.Frontend.GlobalAsaxHandler.Application_OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(sender, e);
    }
}
```

So I can connect. But I can't go to the specific link, like this:
`http://dynamicweb8724.nl/webapi/NavToDW/?process=`

the outcome is this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
bij System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.get_SubRoutes() bij System.Web.Http.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request) bij System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Controller:

```
public class GuestbookApiControllerController : ApiController
{
    // GET: GuestbookApiController
    public IEnumerable<GuestbookEntry> Get()
    {
        return ItemManager.Storage.GetByParentPageId<GuestbookEntry>(1067);
    }
}
```

So what I have to change?

But If I put a breakpoint on this method:

```
public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new Dynamicweb.AspNet.Views.RazorViewEngine());
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new Dynamicweb.AspNet.Views.WebFormViewEngine());
            // Fires when the application is started

            //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            GlobalAsaxHandler.Application_Start(sender, e);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
        }
```

it doesnt hit.

Comment: Where is your `ApiController` code?

Comment: Sorry, but there is no the ApiController

Comment: Why are you configuring web api if you do not use it, then? Any controller in web api *must* inherit from ApiController. I strongly suggest you to read more about Web Api, because there are many issues with your code, and they are not addressable if you do not know the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Your route configuration for the WebApi needs to be fixed. You placed the route template of what you wanted into the name of the route rather than the template itself.

Given the intended Url...

```
http://Dynamicweb8724.nl/webapi/NavToDW/?process="
```

There are a few changes you need to make.

First your api controller needs to be able to accept the parameter `process` and I would also rename the controller to follow convention.

```
public class GuestbookApiController : ApiController
{
    // GET: GuestbookApi
    public IEnumerable<GuestbookEntry> Get(int process)
    {
        return ItemManager.Storage.GetByParentPageId<GuestbookEntry>(process);
    }
}
```

And finally you need to properly map the intended URL to the controller action.

```
public class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {

        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.

        //This will map to the intended controller
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GuestBookApiRoute",
            routeTemplate: "webapi/NavToDW",
            defaults: new { controller = "GuestbookApi" }
        );

        //This is the default api route
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultWebApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }    
}
```

The above shows how to do convention based routing. You can also achieve the same with attribute routing. You can take some time and read up on the topic if you want to do attribute routing